# Abstract algorithm in a class and unknown number of inputs

Tags: python, algorithm, class, parameter-passing

I am trying to code an abstract algorithm class, but I don't know how to manage the plurality of algorithms.

```
class Algorithm:

    def __init__(self, x_init):
        self.x = x_init

    def run(self, n_it):
        for it in range(n_it):
             self.x = self.T(self.x)

    def T(self, x):
         pass
```

It consists to run my algorithm during n_it iterations. My problem is that some algorithms have hyperparameters, so, how can I include them? Furthermore, some algorithms use a step in the past x_{n-1}, and I would

```py
self.x = self.T(self.x, self.x_past)
```

but that does not work with this setup. What is the best solution in your opinion ?

T could be out of the class, but it is more logical for me to be in. I use Algorithm as an abstract class and I create children class for each of my algorithms by defining T. Maybe there is a more efficient way.

I probably can use `*args` and `*kwargs`. Moreover, since I put x as an attribute, I can write

```py
def T(self):
    pass
```

and modify directly in T, it is probably more logical in pythonic way, but a bit less from a mathematical view point. Have you any suggestions to improve my code and solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a functional programming technique here.  Putting an OO design around it creates code for no real benefit.  The following is a simpler version of your code:

```
def run (x, n_it, t):
    for it in range(n_it)
         x = t(x)
    return x
```

And now if someone wants to do things with metaparameters, they can just pass in a closure.

```
def setup_t(parameters):
    prev_x = 0
    def t (x):
        answer = ... # do something with parameters and x
        nonlocal prev_x = x
        return answer
    return t
```

So the caller can handle metaparameters in setup, and track a previous value or three if they need to.  They are better prepared than you to know what complexities they have to deal with, so leave it to them.

Comment: I am not sure to understand (but that seems great). Suppose that I want to iterate the following equation :
x_{n+1} = \alpha * x_n + (1-\alpha) *x_{n-1}
How can I do with your setup ? And an other example could be
x_{n+1} = x_n + 1/n**2

Comment: @NM36 Honestly, I would spend some time studying https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators and just use functional techniques.  So rather than trying to build a framework to pass an algorithm from outside, pass a range into an algorithm and return a generator.